# jQuery $.on() isnt listening to custom native js event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have jQuery listen to an event that is not triggered by jQuery.

Here is the listener:

```
 $(document).on("end.eTime", function (e) {
   console.log("here");
   $("body").append(e.name + " " + e.ellapsed + "<br>");
 });
```

Here is the trigger:

```
var event= new CustomEvent('end.eTime', {custom: object})
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Using newest firefox to test.

If I trigger using jQuery's trigger it works fine, but I'm trying to write a pure js library.

If I try to listen with a native listener it works fine, but I would like to allow users of my library to use jQuery.

Can anyone tell me why jQuery $.on() doesnt want to listen to a native custom event?

### Update

So I removed the namespace as @Derek suggested and then jquery will listen for it correctly. I believe this is a bug so I submitted it here:http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/15143.

I also found, as expected, that native listeners cannot hear jquery events. As @kcent said, they use a completely different process, so its no wonder it doesnt work. The documentation says that it still calls the native events, but this is probably only for things like click. This doesnt effect me for this process, but I still mention in the ticket that it would be nice if it worked.

For a whole series of examples you can check the ticket on jquery.

Comment: I think jquery only picks up jquery events, one of their events could cover more than 1 js event for cross browser. I am sure someone can explain it better than this

Comment: Umm, it works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5W2MN/ , and works with data passed to it: http://jsfiddle.net/V4YVr/ . Native JS events are no different to jQuery. You can listen to JS events with jQuery, but you can't listen to jQuery events with vanilla JS. The problem is probably with the event's namespacing in the jQuery `.on()` call; is there any reason you need to use a `.` in the event name?

Comment: I think the issue is the namespace. I prefer to namespace as its recommended.

Comment: Also to whoever voted me down, may I ask why. Voting down for fun seems to be a frequent thing on SO :(

Comment: To your Update: it's not a bug with jQuery, I'm not sure why you think it is. The idea of namespacing is an important and useful feature of events in jQuery. The thing you should've requested was to know how to "override" it or circumvent it. An idea would be escaping any `"."` in the event name (which I'm sure jQuery doesn't already have the ability to do)

Comment: So you're saying you don't believe jquery should be able to listen for namespaced events created natively, but you do believe it should listen for non namespaced events created natively (which it does)? Seems inconsistent to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling this has to do with the namespace declaration. This works for me with jQuery 2.1 if I name the event 'eTime' instead of 'end.eTime'.

That being said, why wouldn't you use jQuery to trigger the event?

Comment: `but I'm trying to write a pure js library.`

Comment: I agree its the namespace. Wondering if there is any way to still use one, as its a recommended practice.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses it's own internal event registry to keep track of the events that are set & triggered. So, when you created a custom event using native JS, it side-steps that pattern and jQuery doesn't know about it.

If you want to support both, you will likely need to create some custom event methods that register a listener in both native JS and jQuery.

Also side note `CustomEvent` is not available below IE9, if that's a concern for you.

Great reference on custom events: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-custom-events/